# Internet doesn't work on the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have read quite many posts about this topic but nothing was relevant for my "special" case.
Hope someone can help

android sdk: 27
android studio: 3.0.1

My internet connection works correctly and hasn't any problem.
but when I launch emulator, it's not able to use internet.

Can anybody help?

here is the screenshot of my emulator.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: open emulator browser and check internet is working or not

Comment: I've already checked....

Comment: then allow network access to avd from firewall

Comment: how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Android Studio user guide there are 2 possible reasons for the emulator not being able to use your machine's network connection:

> Communication with the emulated device may be blocked by a firewall
>   program running on your machine.
>
> Communication with the emulated device may be blocked by another
>   (physical) firewall/router to which your machine is connected.

However, if your emulator is able to access network (open browser or google play app to check), yet your app isn't - check the manifest file for INTERNET permission:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

EDIT: To solve the problem with the firewall block try launching the Emulator from the command line as follows:

```
emulator -verbose -avd <AVD name>
```

This will give you detailed output and may show the error that's preventing the emulator from connecting to the Internet.

Comment: how can I prevent firewall block the connection of emulator?

Comment: I've edited my answer. This instruction will help you understand the problem nature, then you can either solve it yourself or post the update here for us to help you.

Comment: I wish I could help you, but I can't )) I believe you'll figure it out. It's probably the firewall blocking your emulator. Open the settings see the allowed apps list, try adding Android Studio to them.

Comment: however thanks a lot my friend. I have the best wishes for you form IRAN... :))

Comment: Thank you and best wishes to you too!

Answer (score 0):

It was about some net problem and was not important thing.
it will be fixed after closing and reopening emulator...